# Reload script after ajax request for custom element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a heavily customized questionnaire with a list that is looking like that

```
<ul>  
    <li class="customCheckbox">
    <li class="customCheckbox">
</ul>
```

This questionnaire is loaded by a `JQuery.ajax` call and the js code that comes with it is correctly processed when displayed in a JQuery UI dialog. The `customCheckbox` present on the initial page are correctly processed by my `(function($){ [...] })` in an external script jquery.customCheckbox.js

I need something like `.live()` but since it is removed from JQuery I can't go far with that. I don't want to reload the script in the AJAX call if possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537323/jquery-function-not-binding-to-newly-added-dom-elements) is about the same but me it is not only about an event listener. It modifies the checkbox adding a class and listeners and other stuff.

Actually I am looking for something that would call my `(function($)...` like `$(document).ready`.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: @JoelEtherton How can I reprocess JQuery over a dinamically created element which is not only an event listener that can be fixed with `.on`?

Comment: You've said it in 2 comments, but it doesn't have any meaning or context to me. `reprocess jQuery` -- what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it has replaced .live()

Comment: I can't use .on since it is not simply an event listener. Actually it is more of a JQuery extension written by one of my partners. I know that .on would handle the events on dynamically created elements.

Comment: Johnride - from the jQuery docs description "Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements."

Comment: I know about `.on` I NEED to reprocess JQuery since it IS NOT only an event listener.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap all of your jQuery that you want bound in a function and call it after the ajax is loaded?

Comment: This is very close to what I need but I can't wrap it in a function since I can't edit the code. And I am pretty sure there is a way to call expressely all JQuery functions to run on the loading of a new element. I have seen `evalScripts : true` or something alike with another lib while searching.

Comment: Well thinking about it I can take the whole jQuery function and put it in a function processCheckboxes and call it from the jQuery function. I try that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the code here you are trying to modify or it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Based on what you said, have you tried using `.delegate()`?

```
$('#yourButtonIDContainer').delegate('#yourButtonID', 'click', functionCalled);

function functionCalled(e) { e.preventDefault(); *** Do Something Here **** }
```

Not sure if this helps, but let me know more details if not.