# Javascript hide DIV, Button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi there Stackers,**

I'm back with another problem. It's Javascript (again). I've been creating "alerts" for on my webpage. They contain a button, and I want to close them when I click on a button. However, this doesn't seem to work. I've logged the clicks in the console, and the click is logged. The click does happen.

The Alerts hide after a few seconds. When I change the style with the "Devtools" of Chrome to make it visible again, and click the button then, the DIV does dissapear.

Why does the click not hide my div?

**Javascript**

```
var messageId = 0;

    var alerty = function(type, title, content) {
        messageId++;
    var html = ' <div class="alert" id="a-' + messageId + '"><div class="topview ' + type + '"></div><div class="title">' + title +'</div> <div class="text">' + content +'</div> <input type="button" id="close-'+ messageId + '" class="inputbutton-empty ' + type + '2 button close" value="Meldung schlie&szlig;en"></div>'
    $(html).hide().appendTo("#alertcontainer").fadeIn("fast");
    $(".alert").delay(8000).fadeOut();
    $("#close-" + messageId ).click(function() {
        console.log("XTM: Pushed Alerty alert closed on request.");
        $("#a-" + messageId ).hide("fade", "fast");
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Pascal

Comment: Log `$("#a-" + messageId )` and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: @Malk Yes, I get the at that opened div logged in the console, however, it does not hide.

Comment: So the event is triggering and you are targeting the correct element...what's left? Add a `debugger` line after the log and use the javascript console to work out the jquery syntax that works.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the `delay()` that is preventing your `hide()` call. Try clearing the queue first in your close function:

```
$("#close-" + messageId ).click(function() {
        console.log("XTM: Pushed Alerty alert closed on request.");
        $("#a-" + messageId ).stop().hide("fade", "fast");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you need to use `.on` instead of `.click.`

`.on` is for newly created DOM elements, which you are doing with your html.

See:
[jQuery function not binding to newly added dom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537323/jquery-function-not-binding-to-newly-added-dom-elements)
and
http://api.jquery.com/on/